# High validation accuracy without scaling paramters when using dropout

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, dropout

I was training a CNN network on German traffic sign classifier data. The architecture was-

- 3 convolutional layers with intermediate max pooling
- concatenated outputs of layer 2 and layer 3 to feed to the input layer of the fully connected classifier.
- A final layer giving the softmax probabilities of the classes.
- Used ReLu as the activation function.
- Dropout for regularization only for the input layer of fully connected(FC) network with a keep_prob of 0.5

I did not scale the outputs of the FC input layer neither at the training time nor at the testing time. And while testing used a keep_prob of 1.0. I achieved an accuracy of 99 on validation set and 94 on the testing set.

Now, my question is- How did I achieve this much accuracy without scaling when using dropout?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty much a noobie - but my understanding is that without scaling the input, model takes longer to learn.  I scaled my inputs - image = 1/255.  I did nothing for the outputs - I got numbers too good to be true for validation accuracy (1.0) and loss (0.0000004).  Looking for an explanation I found that unless I scaled my output my validation numbers were bogus.  As noobie I could not figure out how to scale the outputs, so I just killed the =1/255.  My wonderful model was not normal junk:)